# Significant intercept but non-significant coefficients in hierarchical linear modeling (hlm)

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling, linear, intercept

I am a beginner in statistics. I am using hierarchical linear modeling (hlm) to predict the effect of centrality on voice.  The intercept is significant, but the random effects are not significant. Does this matter?
Please help e interpret it.  It is part of  final doctoral research.

The Model for outcome for 1 type of voice is give below:

```
Level-1 Model
    PH_MEANij = β0j + β1j*(GENDERij) + β2j*(AGEij) + β3j*(LMXQ_MEAij) + β4j*(INDEGREEij) + β5j*(V9_Aij) + β6j*(V11_Aij) + rij
Level-2 Model
    β0j = γ00 + γ01*(AGEj) + γ02*(GENDERj) + γ03*(LMXQ_MEAj) + γ04*(LEADERINj)
         + γ05*(V9_Aj) + γ06*(V11_Aj) + u0j
    β1j = γ10
    β2j = γ20
    β3j = γ30
    β4j = γ40
    β5j = γ50
    β6j = γ60

LMXQ_MEA INDEGREE V9_A V11_A have been centered around the group mean.

LMXQ_MEA LEADERIN V9_A V11_A have been centered around the grand mean.
Mixed Model
    PH_MEANij = γ00 + γ01*AGEj + γ02*GENDERj + γ03*LMXQ_MEAj 
    + γ04*LEADERINj + γ05*V9_Aj + γ06*V11_Aj 
    + γ10*GENDERij 
    + γ20*AGEij 
    + γ30*LMXQ_MEAij 
    + γ40*INDEGREEij 
    + γ50*V9_Aij 
    + γ60*V11_Aij 
     + u0j+ rij

Final Results - Iteration 16
Iterations stopped due to small change in likelihood function

σ2 = 0.51302

τ
INTRCPT1,β0        0.94343

Random level-1 coefficient    Reliability estimate
INTRCPT1,β0 0.961
The value of the log-likelihood function at iteration 16 = -1.392670E+02
Final estimation of fixed effects:
Fixed Effect     Coefficient     Standard
error    t-ratio     Approx.
d.f.     p-value
For INTRCPT1, β0
    INTRCPT2, γ00   2.047049    2.414372    0.848   Unable to compute
     AGE, γ01   0.012542    0.081126    0.155   Unable to compute
     GENDER, γ02    -1.109674   5.297362    -0.209  Unable to compute
    LMXQ_MEA, γ03   0.663731    2.578238    0.257   Unable to compute
    LEADERIN, γ04   -0.047921   0.946240    -0.051  Unable to compute
     V9_A, γ05  -0.174489   0.701756    -0.249  Unable to compute
     V11_A, γ06 0.047353    1.639774    0.029   Unable to compute
For GENDER slope, β1
    INTRCPT2, γ10   -0.163073   0.160594    -1.015  100 0.312
For AGE slope, β2
    INTRCPT2, γ20   -0.000987   0.010080    -0.098  100 0.922
**For LMXQ_MEA slope, β3
    INTRCPT2, γ30   0.320799    0.115720    2.772   100 0.007**
For INDEGREE slope, β4
    INTRCPT2, γ40   -0.018409   0.221460    -0.083  100 0.934
For V9_A slope, β5
    INTRCPT2, γ50   0.098819    0.238741    0.414   100 0.680
For V11_A slope, β6
    INTRCPT2, γ60   -0.029678   0.100279    -0.296  100 0.768


The robust standard errors cannot be computed for this model.
Final estimation of variance components
Random Effect   Standard
 Deviation  Variance
 Component    d.f.  χ2  p-value
**INTRCPT1, u0  0.97130 0.94343 1   23.29886    <0.001**
level-1, r  0.71625 0.51302          
Statistics for current covariance components model
Deviance = 278.534020
Number of estimated parameters = 2
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've fixed your question to make the output easier to read. However, to make this question & the model make sense, you have to provide a lot of information, starting with what are all these variables and what data do you have.